# Increase Iphone "Silent mode" notification duration

Tags: iphone, notifications, accessibility, sound-volume

On this device (Iphone SE 2020), you toggle the silent mode with a physical switch on the side.

As far as I can tell, the only way to tell if the silent mode is on is to switch it back and forth : when toggling the silent mode, a small popup appears on the top of the screen for about one second.

This popup is quite small and its duration is too short for this phone user. Is there a way make it longer ?
The notification settings on this phone are apps specific, and I don't see anything relevant to the silent mode.

Comment: Can't you just look at the switch? Down there's a red bar, up it's the colour of the phone body.

Comment: @Tetsujin i will check that. I fear that the case does not make it easily visible